# C# создает параметр реестра в виртуальном каталоге, вместо ожидаемого HKEY_CURRENT_USER

Tags: c#, winforms, реестр, настройки

Подскажите почему C# (winforms)  Win10 записывает значение  в ветку HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\VritualRoot\USER\S-1-5-21--1001\HelloKey
вместо ожидаемого HKEY_CURRENT_USER\HelloKey

```
     RegistryKey currentUserKey = Registry.CurrentUser;
RegistryKey helloKey= currentUserKey.CreateSubKey("HelloKey");
helloKey.SetValue("login", "admin");
helloKey.SetValue("password", "12345");
helloKey.Close();
```

Comment: Может быть потому, что у вас нет прав писать в корень? Вот он и считает вас устаревшим приложением и виртуализирует реестр. Пишите туда, куда рекомендует документация.

Comment: Вы ведь не пишете свои данные в корневой каталог файловой системы?

Comment: А до записи своих данных используйте не старомодный реестр, а Settings.

Comment: настройки правда очень помогли инструкцию взял тут https://habrahabr.ru/post/271483/ по C# и Properties.Settings. Реестром пользуюсь, чтобы без файлов передавать параметр в другое свое приложение, уверен тоже есть инструмент, подскажите в каком направлении посмотреть?

Comment: Для передачи небольшого кол-ва данных в другое приложение до его запуска, можно использовать командную строку. Если нужно чтобы приложения обменивались данными в процессе работы, то есть много способов сделать это, мой любимый это WCF с привязкой net.pipe

Comment: Хочу добавить, что если вы собираетесь передать пароль, то WCF с pipe будет предпочтительнее, чем командная строка. Т.к. командную строку могут увидеть другие приложения.

Comment: @ИванК: Реестр, кстати, тоже могут увидеть других приложения.

Comment: Скажите,  можно получить доступ к данным  Properties.Settings одного приложения, другим? стандартными средствами.   C WCF и net.pipe пока не разобрался

Comment: @VladD согласен, реестр тоже плохой вариант для этих целей.

Comment: @Дмитрий, Settings доступен другим приложениям как и любой другой файл. Стандартных средств для чтения чужого файла Settings не предусмотрено, но вы можете открыть чужой файл настроек, и используя средства чтения XML (например XDocument) прочитать данные. Но это плохой способ для обмена данными между приложениями. Так же это плохой способ для хранения пароля и обмена паролем с другим приложением. Согласитесь, лучше разобраться как сделать правильно чем сразу лепить горбатого.

Comment: @Дмитрий: я не уверен, но по идее можно сделать общую сборку, которая будет заниматься настройками.